# Expose a Springboot rest endpoint to read json object

Tags: json, web-services, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I am new to Springboot and Webservices.Using springboot i need to expose a rest endpoint. Some data provider will call the rest endpoint to post the data. Then i need to start processing the posted json and convert it into a java object. So using spring boot I need to expose a rest webservice to accept and process the json posted to the webservice created. How should I do it. Any example would help

Comment: Well, you certainly have to build a RESTful webservice. Whether or not you need a consumer depends on if the "someone" in "The rest endpoint should be called by someone" is going to be part of a Spring project as well. If that's the case, then "someone" is your consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so simple.
We need to have a Springboot restcontroller to expose rest endpoint. And then using @Requestbody we need to get the Objects directly from the json message passed .

```
@RestController
public class JsonObjectRestController  {

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/pushjson",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<PushedJsonObject> getJsonObject(@RequestBody PushedJsonObject jsonObject)
{
    if(jsonObject != null)
    {
     //process the json object              
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<PushedJsonObject >(jsonObject, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Explanation: 
We need to have a model class representing the json sent(Here its PushedJsonObject). Have your controller annotated with the new Spring4 @RestController. 
The @RequestBody method parameter annotation should bind the json value in the HTTP request body to the java object by using a HttpMessageConverter. Make sure Jackson is in the classpath so that spring boot configures it automatically to use the MappingJackson2MessageConverter.